# Keycloak Invalid token issuer in docker

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, docker, keycloak

I have problem with **keycloak**. So, I have spring-microservices with keycloak. If it start in locally, then good work. But if I start spring and keycloak in docker, then i have problem with security. I get **401 error:** (Bearer realm="bingo", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid token issuer. Expected 'http://keycloak:8080/realms/bingo', but was 'http://localhost:8090/realms/bingo'"). I dont understand, how I can send request to localhost *keycloak:8080*. **Help me, please.**

**Application.properties in spring-app:**

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloak:8080
keycloak.realm=bingo
keycloak.resource=user
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak_auth.password=FXpJokhP8ACMo9h53Hl6NSJXHSk395YG
```

**My docker-compose for keycloak:**

```
  keycloak:
    container_name: 'keycloak'
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: kc_postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - '8090:8080'
    depends_on:
      - kc_postgres
    command: start-dev
    networks:
      - spring
      - kc_postgres
```

So, i get token from react-app. My file for configure keyclaok - keycloak.json:

```
{
  "realm": "bingo",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8090/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "user",
  "public-client": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "FXpJokhP8ACMo9h53Hl6NSJXHSk395YG"
  }
}
```

const keycloak = new Keycloak("keycloak.json");

Comment: Maybe this would help in your `keycloak.json`: `"auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth"`

Comment: @happysongs Oh, no. It's not help. Locally, keycloak are working on port 8090. I also try now set http://localhost:8090/auth, but i get 404 error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the same Keycloak server url between applications.
The problem is that you are running the Spring application in the same network as Keycloak (using `keycloak:8080` to access it) while the React app is using `localhost:8090`.

If you try to run the Spring app locally with

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8090
```

it should work.

To run the Spring application in the docker-compose file, you can try with this configuration

```
keycloak:
    container_name: 'keycloak'
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: kc_postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HTTP_PORT: 8090
    ports:
      - '8090:8090'
    depends_on:
      - kc_postgres
    command: start-dev
    networks:
      - spring
      - kc_postgres
```

then change the Spring property

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://keycloak:8090
```

and React property

```
auth-server-url": "http://keycloak:8090/",
```

and finally set `127.0.0.1 keycloak` in your `/etc/hosts` file (Linux) or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (Windows) so it can be resolved by the React app.

The best thing to do however is to define a DNS entry for Keycloak and then set `KC_HOSTNAME` and `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` to the Keycloak external address.

Comment: Man, thank you a lot!!! :) 
I couldn't solve this problem for a week

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue for me as well. I also needed to update values for `auth-server-url`, `authorization-uri`, `user-info-uri`, `token-uri` from `localhost` to `keycloak` with port `8090`

Answer (score 1):

You can also set dynamically environment variable using entrypoint which will use IP address instead of container name. Keycloak or any other service will be accessible via its original port (8080) both from docker and host network.

```
your-application:
    ...
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        export KEYCLOAK_URL=http://$(getent hosts keycloak | awk '{ print $1 }'):8080/realms/[your-claim-name]
        [your-original-entrypoint]
```

Example:

```
react-app:
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        export KEYCLOAK_URL=http://$(getent hosts keycloak | awk '{ print $1 }'):8080/realms/react
        npm start
```

In my case resolved address is: http://172.20.0.14:8080/realms/react.