# Invalid issuer error in Keycloak token part of docker-compose network

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, keycloak, docker-network, keycloak-services

I have a docker-compose system with a network including a React.js app, a Keycloak app, and a Spring Boot app. The client using a Browser retrieves a Token from the server localhost:8080 and sends the token to the backend which uses the issuer URI keycloak:8080 as it is in the same network and "keycloak" corresponds to the IP of the keycloak container. Thus, the token sent by React has a faulty issuer and leads to the iss error:

```
spring_1    | 2023-05-15T13:02:57.448Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimValidator       : The iss claim is not valid
spring_1    | 2023-05-15T13:02:57.449Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
```

I found a solution in here ([Keycloak Invalid token issuer in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72991550/keycloak-invalid-token-issuer-in-docker?rq=1)) by setting *127.0.0.1 keycloak* as a host, which would allow me to have the correct issuer and still allow to apply the default authentication behavior of keycloak with reference to localhost:8080 but this is only a solution for me locally and would not apply for other clients, so I wanted to ask if someone has an idea on how I can solve this issue. I thought about parsing and adjusting the token manually in the backend by changing localhost to the keycloak IP but this would as far as my knowledge goes not work with the PKCE flow as this would manipulate the content of the token - I do not have much knowledge in this matter yet, so correct me if I am wrong, please.

Another approach I tried was to change the frontend_url to *http://localhost:8080* [image: admin console] and was hoping that Keycloak may take that into consideration but it did not work.

This is the configuration I am using for keycloak with the keycloak-js npm package and I can't change localhost to keycloak as that is the open endpoint to make the authentication by keycloak work:

```
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    url: "http://localhost:8080",
    realm: "mrtapp",
    clientId: "mrtwebapp"
  })
```